# Running on localhost but does not work on the server. (PHP cURL)

Tags: php, curl, cookies, server, localhost

I received an captcha in my localhost but the same code server does not work. I try to run my own server with chmod full authority also gave full authority in the cookie.txt file. When I run the perfect localhost. I think, it does not work because of cookie.txt

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
function open($url, $cookie = "")
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.2) Gecko/20070219 Firefox/2.0.0.2');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 1);
            if($cookie != ""){
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, realpath(dirname(__FILE__))."\cookie.txt");
            }else{
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, realpath(dirname(__FILE__))."\cookie.txt");
            }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.xxxxxx.com/caller/");
    $result = curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
    open("http://www.xxxxxx.com/caller/", 1);
    echo open("http://www.xxxxxx.com/security.php?id=".(floor(rand() * 1000) + 1), 0);
?>
```

Can you help me Please?

Comment: What the hell does _"does not work"_ mean?

Comment: I mean, it does not work on the server.

Comment: Yes, but not working how, does it catch on fire, smoke, make a loud grinding noise or does a Rick Astley video come up?

Comment: mostly you should put <?php phpinfo(); to a info.php file on the server and check if the curl extension is enabled, if not, you need to enable it in the php.ini file.

Comment: Sorry @Richard, Unfortunately, not again . cookie.txt not in any way create a blank file and cookie file does not print even though it constitutes .

Comment: check the curl error paste it before curl close echo curl_error($ch);

Comment: @BiswadeepSarkar  I get blank page . Problem cookie.txt does not create. I'm looking for a solution to this problem .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a security issue. Imagine that an attacker could change your php files and take over your application. That's why Apache server is running under user www-data, which doesn't have access to your files other than read-only. The same applies for directories.

```
if($cookie != "") {
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "/tmp/some_better_name_cookie.txt");
} else {
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "/tmp/some_better_name_cookie.txt");
}
```