# CURL manage Session

Tags: php, session, curl

I'm trying to login a site by CURL. It's working good all, but not saving the session. Mainly it's need to save the session. and also please tell me how to i use this session for visit the site with stay login.

Here is my code.

```
function SiteLogin($url,$data){
    $fp = fopen("cookie.txt", "w");
    fclose($fp);
    session_write_close();

    $login = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40000);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Authorization: 15',
        'Content-Type: application/json'
        ));
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
    ob_start();
    return curl_exec ($login);
    ob_end_clean();
    curl_close ($login);
    unset($login);  
}

$site = "http://picvidcollage.com:6089/pvc/Login";
$data = array(
    'email' => 'users@domain.com',
    'pwd'   => 's3cr3t',
    );
$GrabData   = SiteLogin($site, $data);
$GrabData   = json_decode($GrabData, TRUE);
echo"<PRE>";
print_r($GrabData);
echo"</PRE>";
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to use Cookie jar file

Comment: Please check my code, I already use it.

Comment: What do you mean with `the session is not saved`? Is there a file named `cookie.txt` in your folder? Are you sure php has sufficient rights to create this file? Also why do you have a `return` in your function if there is still more code that has to be executed?

Comment: Note: you have unreached code after return. All echoes after call your function still goes to buffer.

Answer (score 0):

See this link [Running on localhost but does not work on the server. (PHP cURL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37217037/running-on-localhost-but-does-not-work-on-the-server-php-curl/37223555#37223555) I guess your problem is the same. I can add that it's better to use some rand() to have different name of cookie, because if you call the script from outside, different people will share the same cookie and it wouldn't work.

Plus you should put your login and password as a part of the question. I hope you don't use the same password for your other services.